# JS - stop chain of objects methods without error

Tags: javascript, oop

We have some Foo object

```
var Foo = function() {

    this.bar = function(bazinga) {
        if (bazinga) {return this;}
        else {return false;}
    }
    this.show = function() {
        alert('bar');
    }
};
```

So it allows us to do some `foo.bar().bar().bar().bar();` chain.

But if in the middle of chain, bar() will return false, the next bar() attempts will cause error that `undefined has no method bar()` whitch is ofc thing.

So how to make all chain return false without errors whan any of its 'rings' return false?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MXgzx/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the return type of bar. I suggest to create a sort of null object for that purpose and add a finalization method at the end of the chain which returns false for the null object:

```
var Foo = function() {

    var nullFoo = function() {
        this.finalize = function() { return false; }
        this.bar = function() { return this; }
    }
    this.finalize = function() { return this; }
    this.bar = function(bazinga) {
        if (bazinga) {return this;}
        else {return new nullFoo();}
    }
    this.show = function() {
        alert('bar');
    }
}; 

foo.bar().bar().bar().bar().finalize();
```

For your fiddle example I did not use the finalize method but instead gave the null object a show method. Otherwise you still would have `false.show()` at the end:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAVjZ/)**

Comment: +1, it is so called `Null Object Pattern` - good example of how to use it!

Comment: yes, that's where I got the term from. Reference: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NullObject

Comment: Ok I got it. But I worry if it dont gets tricky when classes are bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/MXgzx/5/

**JavaScript:**

```
var Foo = function() {

    var returnValue = true;

    this.bar = function(bazinga) {
        returnValue = returnValue && bazinga;
        return this;
    }
    this.show = function() {
        alert('bar');
        return returnValue;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Method chains can be a bit dangerous. It is all to do with dependencies.

When using method chaining it is a good idea to keep an eye on the objects that each part of the chain returns.

If they are not all the same, e.g they aren't all strings, then it is a good idea to break down the chain into separate statements. Or perhaps extract them into a separate function.

Lets say you have some chain such as

```
somearray.pop().getATagWrapper().getTag().setSrc("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

The implicit dependencies for the chain are Array, Object1, TagWrapper, Tag, String

Now the the function you have written is now coupled to all of these objects and any change to these can potentially wreck havoc with your code.

Where as if we look at

```
someString.trim().substr(12).trim().concat("with awesome")
```

All deals with only the String object.

For more info see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: I am not looking for a javascript or jQuery way of doing it, i already have that. I am looking for ways to this using css animation or translate.